# How to name a class which uses an attribute?

Tags: c#, class, interface, marker-interfaces

I'm coding custom attributes instead marker interfaces

```
public class FooAssignableAttribute : Attribute  
{ 
    ... 
} 

[FooAssignable] 
public class Foo  
{     
   ... 
}
```

Can't I code a dictionary like this?

```
Dictionary<string, FooAssignable> dictionary;
```

Avoiding marker interfaces, I'm trying to use custom attrutes. Why can't I write the above code?

Comment: You can't do this. Attributes aren't part of C#'s type system, and this is not a restriction you can make. Why do you need to express this constraint based on attributes?

Comment: And? so you don't want to, but this is what needs to be done... what's the question?

Comment: I formatted your code samples for you. For future reference, code samples need to be indented four spaces to display properly (or you can use the `{}` button above the edit box).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this doesn't work. The parametric types of a generic collection (or other generic) in C# must be declarable types, and attributes exist only as metadata.

You cannot have an object of type FooAssignable. You can have an object that has the attribute FooAssignable, but this isn't the same as having it as a supertype. FooAssignable is not a class or interface, and isn't a valid type specifier. FooAssignableAttribute is, but that is the type that refers to the attribute itself, not items tagged with that attribute.

Consider that in a Dictionary, the out type for the indexer is the out type you've provided. But you can't have a variable of type FooAssignable- you can have a variable of a type that has been tagged with FooAssignable, but there is no single base class that all those types fit. Since that type declaration is illegal, this Dictionary would have an illegal, nonexistent type as the return type for the getter from its indexer, among many other places. A C# type check cannot be spontaneously replaced via generic mechanisms with an attribute presence check.

Anything you want the type system to check for you has to be part of the type system. Attribute evaluation does not define types, so the type system can't do this for you; meanwhile, generics are the part of the language that most directly interacts with the type system. You'll have to actually go through the type system to perform a check like this, and that does mean promoting FooAssignableAttribute to an interface (IFooAssignable?) instead.

Comment: I didn't have idea of it. But can you explain me more about the last sentence?

Comment: As I understand it, you want a Dictionary that maps strings to objects that have the attribute FooAssignable. That's not possible, because FooAssignableAttribute as a type only refers to the attribute itself- it doesn't mean "objects with the FooAssignable attribute". But if you create a marker interface, IFooAssignable, and make everything you've put your FooAssignableAttribute on implement it, you can make a dictionary from string to IFooAssignable. IFooAssignable is a type that your usable objects can be. A generic collection requires "is a", but relation to an attribute is "has a".

Comment: +1 Looks like you did understand him since the OP switched answers.

Answer (score 1):

`FooAssignableAttribute` is the class's name. If you want to refer to the class in code, you have to use its name.

The shorthand of leaving off the trailing "`Attribute`" only works when you're using it *as* an attribute, like your `[FooAssignable]` example above. When you're using it as a class -- e.g., as a variable declaration, or a generic type argument -- you have to use its class name.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your class name (if possible):

```
public class FooAssignable : Attribute
{ ... }
```

Comment: This doesn't address the problem- Darf Zon wants a collection of (objects tagged with FooAssignable), not a collection of (objects that are of type FooAssignable), which is what this would implement. It's a scope problem, and with no single superclass that implements FooAssignable, there's no way to do this without an interface.

Comment: @AdamNorberg When I answered, Joe White pretty much covered it I thought.  If you look at the revision history of the question, it originally was about trying to use the class name without the "attribute" extension at the end of the keyword, like the way an attribute name decorates a class.  As far as I know, there isn't a rule that Attributes "have to" end with the name "Attribute" attached to them.  Just giving the OP another option since he didn't want the really long name.

Comment: The question got rewritten halfway through my answering it. I'd assumed that the complaint wasn't about the length of the name, but that it's not objects of FooAssignableAttribute that were to be collected, and instead should be "objects of Object that are tagged with FooAssignableAttribute", which isn't itself a type. I seem to have read it wrong, though, based on the acceptance of your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Be coherent with your own style guide or choose any style guide that exists.

Comment: This isn't a problem of style- this is fundamental to the C# type system, and that bound attributes aren't types. Attribute types exist, but objects-tagged-with-an-attribute is not an assignable type.